# How to load prolog files with rules on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using SWI-Prolog and I have a `.pl` file but cannot load it correctly. Not sure if I'm looking in the right places but can't find any info running it on Mac OSX. I should be able to right click on my `.pl` file and open with Prolog and it should work right? It doesn't even work when I do this, always tells me `"Undefined Procedure"`

Using Mac OSX 10.9.2

SWI-Prolog Version 6.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the SWI-Prolog.app application, open it, choose "Consult" from the "File" menu and select your Prolog file. I think the application doesn't (yet?) support consulting a Prolog file  by right-clicking in it and selecting the SWI-Prolog.app application.

Comment: Hm,what's weird is it doesn't have a "File" menu. I only have "swipl-win" Maybe I installed it incorrectly, just found out I have to install XQuartz also. Let me reinstall and hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Yea, reinstalled and everything. I don't have "File" under any menu. Only shows "swipl-win" and there's really nothing under there except "Quit" and "Preferences" and "Hide"

Comment: Edit your question with Mac OS X and SWI-Prolog version information.

Comment: Just did, still unsure why it's not working. I tried `working_directory(CWD, 'directory/of/file').` and I still can't open it via `[file.pl].`

Comment: I'm also running Mac OS X 10.9.2 but with SWI-Prolog.app 7.1.14. Can you try with this SWI-Prolog version? Can you consult a file using `['/full/path/to/the/file.pl']`?

Comment: Hm, thanks that worked perfectly! Why would that work and changing directory and consulting the file not?

Comment: Calling `working_directory/2` to change the current directory and then consulting the file using the syntax `['file.pl']` works fine for me. Are you sure to be writing the `file.pl` between single quotes?